# INSERT data in table with result of a SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to populate a table with the result of a select, but I always get the following error :

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO `fab_bloquer_jours` ( `id`,`day`,`date` ) VALUES ( '','4','2017-12-04 14:55:49' )

My table fab_bloquer_jours is :

```
1   id Primary  int(11)
2   day int(13)
3   date    datetime
```

My query is :

```
$day=$data['fab_bloquer_jours___day'];

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "INSERT INTO fab_bloquer_jours (day)
SELECT * 
   FROM (
        SELECT DATE_ADD('2018-01-01', 
            INTERVAL n4.num*1000+n3.num*100+n2.num*10+n1.num DAY ) AS DATE 
          FROM (
              SELECT 0 AS num
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9
         ) AS n1,
         (
              SELECT 0 AS num
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9
        ) AS n2,
        (
              SELECT 0 AS num
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9
        ) AS n3,
        (
              SELECT 0 AS num
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9
        ) AS n4
    ) AS a
WHERE DATE >= '2018-01-01' AND DATE < '2019-01-01'
  AND WEEKDAY(DATE) = '$day'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$query=$db->execute();
```

I get the `$date` value through a dropdown.

I would appreciate some help here, since I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: You should define column id as AUTO_INCREMENT and remove the id column from the insert.

Comment: Thank you Jay for editing of my post and Raymond for the solution. Indeed, I have forgotten to define the AI into my column. It is working fine now. I can sadly not accept your answer (I guess) because you did just comment my post. And thank you for the other two which responded too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Id and it's empty value, see below:

```
INSERT INTO `fab_bloquer_jours` (`day`,`date`) VALUES ('4','2017-12-04 14:55:49');
```

On your second query, the select statement is wrong. You're trying to insert into one column, but your select statement is saying select all. Anything you make for select statement must be inside of brackets and as one column. e.g.

```
INSERT INTO fab_bloquer_jours (day) VALUES (your SELECT COLUMNNAME FROM TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `id` column on your table to auto increment. Then do not include it on your insert statement.

So, for your example, try this query after you update your id field to auto increment:

```
INSERT INTO fab_bloquer_jours (day,date) VALUES ('4','2017-12-04 14:55:49');
```